# getExternalMediaDirs with null values

Tags: android, crash, scoped-storage

I'm receiving some crashes from users that apparently don't have getExternalMediaDirs(). It returns an array of files with length 1 and null in the [0]. How is this possible?

Seen in Android 8, 9...

Comment: What kind of crashes? Exceptions not catched? And why do you let your app crash if a value is null?

Comment: Because I didn't know that this function could return a null value. I thought scoped storage was always available

Comment: It has nothing to do with scoped storage. And the function does not return null. It returns an array you said.

Comment: Ok, because I didn't know that this function could return an array with a null value. So, what is it related to?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()), the paths can be `null` if the shared storage is unavailable.

Comment: Do you know if this is a temporary problem or why can it happen and how to workaround it?

Comment: It can be transient if the device has an SD card slot. You can use [getExternalStorageState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageState(java.io.File)) to get the status prior to accessing it.